# FLUTTER- Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, apk

I am getting this problem when executing `flutter run` on both Android Studio and VS Code.
I'm new to programming so please tell me if there's anything I could provide to solve this issue.

I try already running `flutter clean` and `flutter build apk` but nothing really changed. The build.gradle file also seems ok, so I don't know where's the issue here.

Also, the .apk file has indeed been generated and it's in the build directory.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.